# How can I social login by jHipster REST api?

Tags: java, spring, jwt, jhipster, spring-social

I want use jHipster for native mobile app backend. I can register and login through api REST perfectly.

But, how I do a social login through api? I cant find any endpoint

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you included all necessary dependency in your POM file ?
If yes then you need to make some configurations in properties files and other files in order to configure them. It is explained in more detail [Here](http://www.jhipster.tech/tips/012_tip_add_new_spring_social_connector.html).
I am sure this will help you.